# Problem including file with "source" command in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a config.ini file that contains some variables, like PATH, ORACLE_HOME,.... when I include the file with "source" command it brings the file, the values,... but it doesn't work.

When I copy the content of this file into my sh it works.

Config.ini File

```
ORACLE_HOME="/ora121/app/oracle/product/12.1.0"
```

SH File

```
source ./config/config.ini

export ORACLE_HOME
export PATH
```

Comment: we can't tell what you mean by "it doesn't work". Please add some debug output after your `export` cmds, i.e. `echo "ORACLE_HOME=${ORACLE_HOME}XX and PATH=${PATH}ZZ"` maybe. Then edit your Q to show the output from that `echo` cmd. Also, what is the first line of your script, i.e. `#!/bin/sh`, and what OS are you running under. Edit your Q to include output of `uname -srv`. Good luck.

Comment: `source` is a non-standard (though more readable) alias for `.`. The shell you are using to execute the `sh` file may not understand `source`; use `.` instead.